# SSRS 2019 DNS Entries Give 404 when trying to run reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2019, ssrs-2019

I have set up a new SSRS 2019 site with HTTPS & DNS.  When I am connecting to the site through the https://ComputerFQDN/Reports then everything works just fine.  When I try to connect through DNS to https://DNSName/Reports then the main page comes up and everything functions, until I try to run a report and then I get a 404 error.  I can't figure out what setting I am missing or why all the reports work with the FQDN but fail with DNS alias.

Certificate is good and has the FQDN + DNS entries.

Tried with multiple DNS entries and get the same error.

Tried multiple browsers with same results and multiple computers.

I have checked that the DNS entries are both in the URL ACL and the RSReportServer.config files.

Server is configured to only use HTTPS.

Server is not running IIS.

This is an on-prem install and not in the cloud.

SQL 2019 with an Always On High Availability cluster.

I've read everything I can find, but so far I have not been able to find an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved.  The DNS entries were not properly input into the URLACL for ReportServer.

When looking at the "netsh http show urlacl" command we noticed that the /Reports entries were present for the DNS entries, but were not present for the /ReportServer entry.  Once we added the entries for the /ReportServer then it started working correctly.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant - I've had store the DNS names in BackConnectionHostNames in the registry as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, albeit with TLS setup, but I don't think that makes any difference.

I tried the command above "netsh http show urlacl" which showed me that the SSRS web portal was indeed setup on https://localhost/Reports (the web service was actually working). However, navigating to that gave me a 404 Not Found error. I confirmed this 404 error was being served up by SSRS, by stopping SSRS and refreshing the page, which then gave a "Hmmm… can't reach this page" error in Edge.

All I did was change it to "https://localhost/Reports2" in Report Server Configuration Manager and then back again to "https://localhost/Reports". SSRS went through a few steps to clean / change the setup and it all worked afterwards.

I think changing the "Report" segment caused SSRS to reset the configuration a bit more thoroughly.